# Compare dates in a list

Tags: bash, text-processing, date

So I have a list of dates and I need to develop a script that keeps a rolling count of how many dates are older than 14 days (`date --date="14 days ago" +%Y%m%d`). Not sure how I can have the date check through a file.  Most of the research I find shows me how to come timestamps, which is not what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
20160517
20160518
20160519
20160520
20160521
20160522
20160523
20160524
20160525
20160526
20160527
20160528
20160529
20160530
20160531
20160601
20160602
20160603
20160604
20160605
20160612
20160612
20160615
20160615
20160615
20160615
20160615
20160615
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming there's a file called `dates` containing the list of dates, one per line (and nothing else), something like this might work to count the ones older than 14 days:

```
$ date=$(date --date="14 days ago" +%Y%m%d)
$ awk '($0 < "'$date'") {count += 1} END {print count}'  < dates
20
```

(Given they are in `yyyymmdd` format, the comparison is easy.)